# How can I make sure results from a CASE Statement are not shown in my query?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, alias

I am working on an evaluation project in Oracle and would like to know how I can make sure results from a CASE Statement are not shown in my query.  I've tried using the ALIAS name, but it does not like it since it is an 'invalid identifier.'  I was told you cannot use an ALIAS name in the 'Where' clause?  Not sure if that is correct or not.

I'm sure it is something simple, but I cannot find the issue.  Here is what I am working on so far:

```
--QUERY 1--
SELECT Department 
       , Full_Name_Supervisor
       , Supervisor_Email
       , Full_Name, Email_Address
       , Start_Date
       , Classification
       , Job_Title
       , State_or_Local_Fund
    --   ,(extract(DAY from Start_Date)||'/'||extract(MONTH from Start_Date)||'/'||extract(YEAR from sysdate))
--START OF CASE STATEMENTS--
,(CASE WHEN Classification = 'CS' THEN
      (CASE WHEN add_months(Start_Date, 3) BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate - 30) AND trunc(Sysdate - 1) THEN '3M 30 Days Past'
             WHEN add_months(Start_Date, 3) BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate) AND trunc(Sysdate + 89) THEN '3M Next 90 Days'
             WHEN add_months(Start_Date, 6) BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate - 30) AND trunc(Sysdate - 1) THEN '6M 30 Days Past'
             WHEN add_months(Start_Date, 6) BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate) AND trunc(Sysdate + 89) THEN '6M Next 90 Days'
             WHEN add_months(Start_Date, 12) BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate - 30) AND trunc(Sysdate - 1) THEN '12M 30 Days Past'
             WHEN add_months(Start_Date, 12) BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate) AND trunc(Sysdate + 89) THEN '12M Next 90 Days'
             WHEN to_date(decode(extract(DAY from Start_Date)||'/'||extract(MONTH from Start_Date),'29/2','28/2',extract(DAY from Start_Date)||'/'||extract(MONTH from Start_Date))||'/'||extract(YEAR from sysdate),'dd/mm/yyyy') BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate - 30) AND trunc(Sysdate - 1) THEN 'Annual 30 Days Past'
             WHEN to_date(decode(extract(DAY from Start_Date)||'/'||extract(MONTH from Start_Date),'29/2','28/2',extract(DAY from Start_Date)||'/'||extract(MONTH from Start_Date))||'/'||extract(YEAR from sysdate),'dd/mm/yyyy') BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate) AND trunc(Sysdate + 89) THEN 'Annual Next 90 Days'

      END)
  WHEN Classification = 'AP' THEN
        (CASE  WHEN to_date('01-JAN'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)+ 1),'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN trunc(sysdate - 30) AND trunc(sysdate - 1) THEN 'Annual 30 Days Past'
               WHEN to_date('01-JAN'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)+ 1),'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate) AND trunc(Sysdate + 89) THEN 'Annual Next 90 Days'      
        END)
  WHEN Classification = 'ST' THEN
       (CASE WHEN to_date('01-MAY'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN trunc(sysdate - 30) AND trunc(sysdate - 1) THEN 'Semester 30 Days Past'             
             WHEN to_date('01-MAY'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate) AND trunc(Sysdate + 89) THEN 'Semester Next 90 Days' 
             WHEN to_date('01-AUG'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN trunc(sysdate - 30) AND trunc(sysdate - 1) THEN 'Semester 30 Days Past'             
             WHEN to_date('01-AUG'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate) AND trunc(Sysdate + 89) THEN 'Semester Next 90 Days' 
             WHEN to_date('01-DEC'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN trunc(sysdate - 30) AND trunc(sysdate - 1) THEN 'Semester 30 Days Past'             
             WHEN to_date('01-DEC'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN trunc(Sysdate) AND trunc(Sysdate + 89) THEN 'Semester Next 90 Days' 
        END)
END) AS Evaluation_Due  --This is the last column which only Non-Null values should be shown.

FROM
--Query 2--
(SELECT DISTINCT
   (SELECT Min(q2.effective_start_date)
        FROM hr.per_all_assignments_f q2
            WHERE q2.assignment_id = paaf.assignment_id
                  AND 'Evaluation_Due' > ' '
                 AND q2.job_id = paaf.job_id) AS Start_Date 
   ,papf.email_address          Email_Address
   ,papf.full_name              Full_Name
   ,haou.name                   Department
   ,pjd.segment6                Classification
   ,pjd.segment9                Job_Title
   ,ppapf.full_name             Full_Name_Supervisor
   ,ppapf.email_address         Supervisor_Email
   ,(CASE when substr(pcak.segment1, 2,3) = '810' then 'State'
          when substr(pcak.segment1, 2,3) = '010' then 'State'
              ELSE 'Local'
END) State_or_Local_Fund
FROM hr.per_all_people_f papf,
     hr.per_all_assignments_f paaf,
     hr.per_all_people_f ppapf,
     hr.hr_all_organization_units haou,
     hr.per_jobs pj,
     hr.per_job_definitions pjd,
     hr.pay_cost_allocations_f pcaf,
     hr.pay_cost_allocation_keyflex pcak
--Joining fields--
WHERE paaf.person_id = papf.person_id
AND papf.person_id = paaf.person_id
AND paaf.organization_id = haou.organization_id
AND pcak.cost_allocation_keyflex_id = pcaf.cost_allocation_keyflex_id
AND pcaf.assignment_id = paaf.assignment_id
AND pj.job_definition_id = pjd.job_definition_id
AND paaf.job_id = pj.job_id    
AND ppapf.person_id (+) = paaf.supervisor_id
-- Truncating sysdate--
AND trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
AND trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN paaf.effective_start_date and paaf.effective_end_date
AND trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN pcaf.effective_start_date and pcaf.effective_end_date
AND trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN ppapf.effective_start_date (+) and ppapf.effective_end_date (+)
--Constraints--
AND (pjd.segment3 != 'E'
AND pjd.segment9 != 'Retiree'
AND pjd.segment6 IN ('CS','AP','ST')
AND paaf.assignment_status_type_id = 1

))
```

Let me know if more information is needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Make the query a subquery or CTE and use a `where` clause on the outer query.

Comment: You asked, "How I can make sure results from a CASE Statement are not shown in my query?" Um... don't put it in a select...  what's the case statement needed for? it's not in the where presently so other than output, it serves no purpose and if you don't want it as the output, then why have a case in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, some results will occur based on where the system date currently is. The query that is above is providing everything: NON-NULL values and NULL values.  How can I remove the NULL values so I am not seeing blank fields in my Evaluation_Due column?  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes - then what Gordon said, wrap this in an outer query and apply the `where` clause against that; the column alias will be valid for the outer query. You just can't use it in the same level of query (except in the `order by`).

Comment: Alex and Gordon, thank you for explaining the reason behind why the ALIAS cannot be used in the same level of query.  I'll try the Outer Query tomorrow and post back with the results.  Thanks!

Comment: Outer query worked like a charm.  Thanks guys!